# Saving multiple arrays in a text file (python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save

I have 500 arrays named A0 to A499 (All arrays are of different sizes). I want to save these arrays in a text file. Is there any way to get my job done? Also, if possible, I would like to keep their names (A0,A1 etc) so that it is easier to recall later.
I am able to save a single array using np.savetxt but i have no idea how to do it for these 500 arrays.
Thank you very much.

```
for i in range(500):
    exec("A%s=SMtoM(outputS(115,15,0.62))"%(i))
```

this is how I made my 500 Arrays!

Comment: have you tried looking at the pickle module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pickle :

```
import pickle

def load(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        my_lists = pickle.load(f)
    return my_lists

def save(filename, my_lists):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(my_lists)

# Where my_lists = [A0, A1, ..., A499]
```

Comment: Thanks and Sorry! Is there any way to make different arrays A0, A1, ..., A499 into a single list [A0,A1,A2...A99]? I mean, how shall i define my_list if all my arrays are seperate?

Comment: You can work that at the declaration of your lists? Like, initialize them from the beginning. A = [[0 for k in range(length)] for k in range(400)] and replace in your program A0, A1, ..., A499 by A[0], A[1], ..., A[499]. Don't know if it's available for you but sure there might be another way that I don't see here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
outpt= open("file.txt", "w")
for array in arraylist:
  # write each array as a line
  outpt.write(arraylist)
  outpt.write("\n")
outpt.close()
```

Pickle works even better as mentioned above.